# Как указать исключения для "wget" при скачивании сайта?

Tags: wget

Пытаюсь скачать сайт целиком через WGET, но требуется исключить некоторые URL по маске.
Например нужно исключить страницы такого вида:

- http://site.ru/stranica/**feed**
- http://site.ru/stranica/**?replytocom=12345**

Нужно исключить все страницы, в которых есть "feed" либо "replytocom".

Делаю так:

```
wget -r -k -l 7 -p -nc -np -R "*replytocom*","*/feed*" http://site.ru/
```

Но эти страницы все равно скачиваются.

Comment: --exclude-directories

Comment: тоже не помогает

Comment: тогда,  вероятнее, этой опции нет во вгет!